# How to update an object in double nested array using mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

```
const AnswerModel = new Schema({
    questionid: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'questionsModel'
    }
    ,
    allanswers: [{
        user: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'users' },
        answers: [{
            answer: {
                type: String,

            },
            isTrue: {
                type: Boolean,
                default: false
            },
            date: {
                type: Date,
                default: Date.now
            }

        }]

    }]
})

Answers.findOneAndUpdate({ questionid: ObjectId(req.body.questionid) },
                    {
                        $set: { allanswers: { user: ObjectId(req.body.userid) } },
                        $push: { answers: { answer: req.body.answer } }
                    },
                    { useFindAndModify: false }
                )
                    .then(res => console.log(res))
                    .catch(err => console.log(err))
```

The query above sets the username in allanswers array but doesnt push a new object inside answers array. everytime someone submits a new answer i want to match questionid, check if user has submitted and answer before, I do this by:

```
  Answers.findOne({ questionid: ObjectId(req.body.questionid) })
        .then(onequestionanswer => {
            if (onequestionanswer.allanswers.filter(oneuseranswers => oneuseranswers.user.toString() === req.body.userid).length === 0)
```

then if it hasnt i want to set a new user in allanswers and add the answer to answers array, if user has already submitted an answer before i want to match the user in allanswers array, then push new answer to the answers array. Is there a way to do this both in one query, if not how can i fix my query to push answers in answers array?

Answer (score 0):

try this code i think it's works.

```
Answers.findOne({
    $and: [
        {
            questionid: ObjectId(req.body.questionid)
        },
        {
            'allanswers.user': ObjectId(req.body.userid)
        }]
}).exec(function (err, result) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err)
    } else if (result) {
        //if user match then push answer in answers array
        const ansObj = {    // your ans object
            answer: req.body.answer,
            isTrue: false,
            date: new Date()
        }
        Answers.findOneAndUpdate({
            $and: [
                { questionid: ObjectId(req.body.questionid) },
                { 'allanswers.user': ObjectId(req.body.userid) }
            ]
        },
            {
                $push: { 'allanswers.$.answers': ansObj }
            },
        ).exec(function (err, result) {
            console.log(err, 'errerrerr')
            console.log(result, 'resultresultresult')
        })
    } else {
        //if user id not match push object in allanswers array
        const FirstAnsObj = {     //your ans object
            user: new ObjectId(),
            answers: [{
                answer: req.body.answer,
                isTrue: false,
                date: new Date()
            }]
        }
        Answers.findOneAndUpdate({ questionid: ObjectId(req.body.questionid) },
            {
                $push: { allanswers: FirstAnsObj }
            },
        ).exec(function (err, result) {
            console.log(err, 'errerrerr')
            console.log(result, 'resultresultresult')
        })
    }
})
```

- first check user is exist or not
- second if user exist the push the answer in `answers` array
- third if user not exist then push the user in `allanswers` array